# update _ids values by sorted timestamp with sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, timestamp

i have a few tables look like below (sqlite)

table a:

| a_id (unique) | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 123 |
| 2 | 178 |
| 33 | 101 |
| 7 | 221 |
| 4 | 115 |

table b:

| b_id (unique) | a_id | data (no need to sort) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 4 | bb |
| 3 | 2 | dd |
| 22 | 21 | ee |
| 6 | 7 | xx |
| 17 | 2 | tt |
| 11 | 33 | qq |

now i want to update these tables' _id according to the timestamp in a as follows:

table a:

| a_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 115 |
| 3 | 123 |
| 4 | 178 |
| 5 | 221 |

table b:

| b_id | a_id | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | qq |
| 2 | 2 | bb |
| 3 | 3 | ee |
| 4 | 4 | dd |
| 5 | 2 | tt |
| 6 | 5 | xx |

how can i do this easily with sql, without re inserting the data etc?

thanks

i used to create a dummy column with new and sorted ids by timestamp, then update other tables accordingly but it was inefficient and i have forgotten how i did it

**update:**

to simplify, i want to create a new column sort_id in table a, which holds the value according to the sorted timestamp, so

before:

table a

| a_id (unique) | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 123 |
| 2 | 178 |
| 33 | 101 |
| 7 | 221 |
| 4 | 115 |

after:

table a

| a_id (unique) | timestamp | sort_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 123 | 3 |
| 2 | 178 | 4 |
| 33 | 101 | 1 |
| 7 | 221 | 5 |
| 4 | 115 | 2 |

so how can i fill the sort_id column according to the timestamp?

Comment: Please edit your question to use the formatting I have demonstrated for you.

Comment: You should ***never*** alter an id after it has been created, the whole of SQL is designed around never even needing to. An id should ***only*** uniquely identify a row, and never even ***imply*** anything else. If you need to know the relative order of something, that should be in another column. So, the reason this is clunky to achieve is; you should ***not*** be doing this. Doing this isn't just an anti-pattern, it's unreliable and is dangerous from a referential integrity perspective. *(Why do you **think** you need this, what functionality are you trying to achieve?)*

Comment: @MatBailie sorry about the formatting, i am a newbie who still dont understand how to format the question properly, eg i had to re edit the question by adding extra blank lines or otherwise lines will be shown in a single line. and i know it's not an usual practice but this db is read by a program, which will show the result according to the _id. under normal circumstances it is fine but if the db is recovered due to some problems, the _ids will look like this and thus producing inaccurate outputs

Comment: It's not unusual practice. It's wrong, an anti-pattern, can damage referential integrity, and almost certainly has a solution using correct relational database patterns. Until you elaborate on precisely what you're trying to work around, you're going to be stuck trying to drive a screw with a hammer.

Comment: also tag your database

Comment: @MatBailie i have updated the tables and the solution i want to have already.

Comment: Different dialects of SQL will solve this differently, so it's important to follow @eshirvana's advice; tag your database. MySQL5.x, MySQL 8, Oracle, SQLite, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, etc, etc?

Comment: tag added, it's sqlite. sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to query your table b data and sort it based on time stamp .

order of rows in a database is not guaranteed at all and it changes anytime after each insert/update, so you need to join two tables and sort based on timestamp column :

```
select  b.*
from table_b b
left join table_a a 
   on a.a_id = b.a_id
order by a.timestamp
```

depending on your sqlite version you also can use [`update from`](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html#upfrom) :

```
update tableb
set sort_id = rn
from (select a_id , row_number() over (order by timestamp) as rn from tableA) tableA
where tableA.a_id = tableB.a_.id
```

Comment: hi @eshirvana, i have update my question which should be a proper and better solution. any idea how to fill the sort_id column pls?

Comment: hi @eshirvana, it works and i am able to perform similar operations to other tables now. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Aftrer you've altered the table to add the new column...

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    a_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS new_sort_id
  FROM
    table_a
)
UPDATE
  table_a
SET
  sort_id = sorted.new_sort_id
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  table_a.a_id = sorted.a_id
```

Comment: the with statement failed unless i appended an extra line: select _id from sorted natural join table_a. while the update statement produced an error: near "UPDATE": syntax error

Comment: @xxjoe - are you sure you're using SQLite? It works perfectly fine here; https://dbfiddle.uk/1wX4mdRz. Please quote the ***entire*** error message, and double check the database and version?

Comment: Why do you have `natural join` in your code? You're not testing this answer. You're adapting this code to something else, then asserting that this answer has an issue? Please open a new question to address the new issue you're facing, because it's becoming clear that it's not the same question as above.

Comment: strange, it works on dbfiddle... i appended the join statement because with the with statement itself it failed: Result: incomplete input. i modified it to a simpliest way as below but still failed: WITH sorted AS(  SELECT a_id AS new_sort_id FROM table_a). let me play with dbfiddle for a while

Comment: You need to select ***both*** `a_id` and `new_sort_id`, and the new_sort_id should be derived from row_number, which isn't even in your code snippet. You certainly shouldn't refer to the sorted CTE inside its own definition.